# How to use Default Back Button in Android Application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android...

I have created an android application in which in my Main Activity i added No. of buttons in that class..

Also when user click on particular button it shows other class(I have created draw-method inside view class)

When I click a **Button event** it shows related view class & when i click default back button it is going to MainActivity Class..that's Fine for me..

Now Issue is when i Want to close the application using Default Back Button On MainActivity 
it is not done..Repeatedly calling mainActivity..
Sorry for my English

I am using this Code for Back Button
**In MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0))
       //if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.KEYCODE_BACK == 1))
   {
       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
      // Intent intent=new Intent();

       startActivity(intent);
       return true;

   }


   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you want to quit your application on Android Back button. But when I refer your code you are intentionally starting the MainActivity rather than calling finish();

Answer (score 4):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method of activity.
for this rather than `keyEventListener`.
use `super.onBackPress();` whenever you want default back action.
when you want to finish activity then call `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

1. In most cases if you want to handle the "back button" is better if you use `onBackPressed`
2. Fix your problem without more info can't be fixed because you should change the logic a bit. I mean: After the first "Back" it should exit if back is pressed again? Or what? When the application should do? Because right now, the code does what you want you didn't add nothing to let happen the default code (`finish()`)
3. I'm thinking to something like this

   ```
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      // more than one press, so we want to close
      if (event.getRepeatCount() > 1) {
        finish();
      } else { // just one, so open the activity
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);    
        startActivity(intent);
      }
   }
   ```

   While it *could* work, you should change your design. Back button go "BACK" don't open something of new.